# Stored procedure for multiple schemas

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to create a stored procedure that adds a student record to a table and can be used by multiple schemas, but should only affect the table belonging to the specific schema. What I have so far is this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE AucklandPark.#add_student
     (@studentNum INT, 
      @firstName NVARCHAR(60), 
      @lastName NVARCHAR(60), 
      @address NVARCHAR(60))
AS
    INSERT INTO AucklandPark.StudentInfo
    VALUES (@studentNum, @firstName, @lastName, @address);
```

It works, but only for the `AucklandPark` schema. If I try to create a stored procedure that does the same thing but I replace `AucklandPark` with something else, I get an error saying that the stored procedure already exists.

Comment: You will have to use dynamic SQL. Use OBJECT_SCHEM_NAME(@@PROCID) to get the stored procedure's schema.

Comment: @NițuAlexandru I don't understand what you mean. Where and how do I use OBJECT_SCHEM_NAME(@@PROCID)?

Comment: Although you specify a schema name for your procedure, the procedure is temporary (# before name), it will be created in tempdb, but does not need a schema name to be called. First of all, why are you creating this procedure temporary?

Comment: @NițuAlexandru It refused to let me use the procedure when I didn't put # in front.

Comment: Who or what is "it"? What's the error if you don't put #? Do you have rights to create stored procedure on this database?

Comment: This is a database that I made for a project. The error it throws when I try to use the stored procedure says the procedure could not be found. I've decided to just make a procedure for every schema.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE AucklandPark.#add_student(@studentNum INT, @firstName NVARCHAR(60), @lastName NVARCHAR(60), @address NVARCHAR(60))
AS
    DECLARE @SchemaName VARCHAR(100) = OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(@@PROCID)

    DECLARE @Query NVARCHAR(MAX) = CONCAT('INSERT INTO ', QUOTENAME(@SchemaName), '.StudentInfo VALUES (@studentNum, @firstName, @lastName, @address);')

    EXEC sp_ExecuteSQL @Query,
        N'@studentNum INT, @firstName NVARCHAR(60), @lastName NVARCHAR(60), @address NVARCHAR(60)',
        @studentNum,
        @firstName,
        @lastName,
        @address
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is one proc to update all campus/schemas.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.[#add_student]
     (@studentNum INT, 
      @firstName NVARCHAR(60), 
      @lastName NVARCHAR(60), 
      @address NVARCHAR(60),
      @campus NVARCHAR(128)
)
AS
    select -- if ' then '' to escape. string now, not parameter
         @firstName = replace(@firstName,nchar(39),nchar(39)+nchar(39)) 
        ,@lastName = replace(@lastName,nchar(39),nchar(39)+nchar(39))
        ,@address = replace(@address,nchar(39),nchar(39)+nchar(39))
        ,@campus = replace(@campus,nchar(39),nchar(39)+nchar(39));
    declare @s nvarchar(max) = '
    INSERT INTO ' + quotename(@campus) + '.StudentInfo
    VALUES (' + rtrim(@studentNum) + ',''' + @firstName + ''',''' + @lastName + ''',''' + @address + ''');';
    exec(@s);
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a temporary stored procedure because the `#` name prefix. Temporary stored procedures are created in tempdb dbo schema. The schema name specified in `CREATE PROCEDURE` is ignored in this case as well as when executed. To wit:

```
USE YourDatabase;
GO
CREATE PROC SomeArbirarySchema.#example
AS SELECT 1;
GO
```

The procedure is created in the tempdb `dbo` schema as the query below shows.

```
SELECT OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb.SomeArbirarySchema.#example'), DB_ID(N'tempdb'));
```

This proc can be called with any of these constructs:

```
EXECUTE #example;
EXECUTE SomeArbirarySchema.#example;
EXECUTE ThisCanBeAnyString.#example;
```

The schema name of the objects referenced within the proc body is honored.

If your intent is to create temporary procs that reference objects that differ only by schema name, you'll need to use different temporary procedure names rather than using the schema name as a namespace.